# create custom complex layout with best approach in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I built a layout but I know this is not good way to create this layout.
so how to get  the best approach to create this layout with dynamic and alignment of middle widget should in center .

CODE:

```
class StartGroupChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  double startPoint = 30;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  color: MyTheme.secondryColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Text(
                "GROUP CHAT",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: MyTheme.secondryColor),
              ),
            ],
          )),
      body: Container(
        color: MyTheme.grey800,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            InkWell(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: size.height * 0.14,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3957694.jpg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 30,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZDA1ODgyODEtOWI3Yy00N2UzLTk5ZGMtZGI1MzU5YzFkZDQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTc4MzI2NQ@@._V1_UY1200_CR285,0,630,1200_AL_.jpg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 60,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhS1n9AgNPFrsPjj0fHqwPdIJPJLl9hXUq5Q&usqp=CAU",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 90,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://img.mensxp.com/media/content/2020/Aug/Michele-Morrone-From-365-Days-Floored-Us-With-His-Fashion-Game-1200x900_5f2a761253b66_1200x900.jpeg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 120,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS44UpSZW-GZwDVxU3763H9HPOWqdB6ThRAoQ&usqp=CAU",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 150,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://img1.nickiswift.com/img/gallery/the-untold-truth-of-michele-morrone-from-365-days/intro-1593017194.jpg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 180,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_fill,w_720,ar_16:9,f_auto,q_auto,g_auto/shape/cover/sport/Bar-Giuseppe-Red-Carpet---14th-Rome-Film-Fest-2019-7de8f118ccdbce430f2d706463c8e09c.jpg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: startPoint + 210,
                            child: UserAvatar(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://stat2.bollywoodhungama.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Netflixs-365-Days-breakout-star-Michele-Morrone-looks-sharp-on-the-cover-of-Elle-India-..jpg",
                                avatarRadius: size.height * 0.12),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "START CHAT",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: MyTheme.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 28.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.08,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyTheme.primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "CONTINUE",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

USER AVATER:

```
class UserAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final double avatarRadius;

  const UserAvatar({Key key,@required this.imageUrl , @required this.avatarRadius}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: avatarRadius,
      width: avatarRadius,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
          fit: BoxFit.cover
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?)

Comment: to align the stack in center you can wrap it with `container` then you can `align` it center. and give width to the container as `double.infinity` or `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`.

Comment: Would you please implement, where should be?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was good

But it seems repetitive, i think you should add another field properties like the position of image and also avatar radius because its have same repetitive const value

```
UserAvatar(
     imageUrl: "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3957694.jpg",
     imageNo : 1,
),
),
```

So the widget should be like this

```
class UserAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final double avatarRadius;
  final int imageNo;

  const UserAvatar({Key key,@required this.imageUrl , @required this.avatarRadius}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  double startPoint = 30;
  final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Positioned( 
left: startPoint + (30 * imageNo),
Container(
      height: size.height * 0.12,
      width: size.height * 0.12,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
          fit: BoxFit.cover
        )
      ),
    ),
);
  }
}
```

And moreover actually you can also move the body for the show avatar
from line 37 ~ 100 because it is constant value